# UE4 lerping large amount of meshes with good performances

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have been working on a small prototype for a project of mine. The goal is to have a procedural wall made of cube that when someone subscribe from twitch the according cube light's up to make his name appear. I decided to use instancedStaticMesh because of the sheer amount of cube I need (im using a 100x100 grid for the moment) so that the cube can form letters. I was able to make the cube change and make names appear with still good performances. The problem I am running into is that I would like the cubes on the wall to dynamically lerp a bit constantly to help make the wall more dynamic and not feel static. This is where the problem appear, it just doesn't seem possible to do this type of thing with an instancedStaticMesh at this scale and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to do it without utterly destroying performances.

Comment: Interesting idea. Is this for a vtuber project or something? If so, I'd be interested in following progress on github or something. As for how you can proceed, I wonder if this could be helped with custom (vertex) shader code where you just have the vertices move as a function of time, maybe offsetting the time based on the object's position so you get a wave appearance.

Comment: This is for the backround of a stream with interactivity. I was able to make what I wished in a niagara system. As I didn't get what I wanted from meshes and weren't sure what to do I simply did a niagara system :). I still let the ticket open as I would really like to know if you can do what I describe with meshes as this would simplify some other processes I have going on.